# Editing req.user object

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am running a basic authentication strategy in express for passport directly out of the tutorials.

(Facebook strategy shown below as it is common, I'm actually using passport-saml, but this question relates to all passport strategies):

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback"
  },
  function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {
      //HOW DO I ATTACH THE profile OBJECT HERE TO THE PASSPORT USER?
      //OR IS THERE ANOTHER WAY TO SAVE profile FOR LATER? (without using a database)
      return cb(null, profile);
  }
));
```

I need to edit the `req.user` object, and append the `profile` object from the passport callback. This will enable the user session to have user specific profile data.

I will then use the `req.user` with the added `profile` in the authentication middleware:

```
//MIDDLEWARE TO CHECK IF USER IS LOGGED IN
function authUser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user) {
        //I WANT TO HAVE THE profile AVAILABLE HERE
        next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}
```

How can I edit the passport user object to have the extra profile information available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to modify `req.user` doesn't seem like the best practice to have (if it would even work). I believe `req.user` should be, at all times, identical to the user in your database.

However, you could use `passReqToCallback` to use req in the Passport callback, and set `req.session` accordingly.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    clientID: FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "/auth/facebook/callback",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) {  
      req.session.profile = profile;
      return cb(null, profile);
  }
));
```

You should then remember to delete the `req.session.profile` on any request where `req.user` isn't defined in order to not keep outdated `profile` information on logged-out users.

```
app.get("*", function(req, res, next){
    if(req.session.profile && !req.user)
        delete req.session.profile;
    next();
});
```

All of this is untested, but I believe it could work for you.

Comment: I see you accepted this answer, did you manage to find a workaround for your specific case?

Comment: Yes, I tested your answer and it is the way to go for the facebook strategy. It also works for the `passport-saml` `SamlStrategy`. As of now there is a reported bug in the `MultiSamlStrategy` that does not `passReqToCallback` if you are using multiple SAML auth points. I posted the workaround for that in my answer below. I'm still not sure about your comment about the `profile` being stored in db. I'm not sure all data from IP should be stored in the DB, maybe some like userId?

Answer (score 0):

`passport-saml` answer that probably works for other strategies:

The `profile` gets saved to the user object automatically.

The trick is that if the user attribute is blank it is not saved. IE:

```
{nameId:'russHanneman', sessionId: undefined}
```

The sessionId will not make its way into the user object. If you need to adjust the user cookie to be different than the returned `profile`, you can do so when it is being serialized:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, {
      id: "custom value",
      nameId: user["userName"],
      email: user["email"]
   });
});
```

Configuring and serializing in passport:
http://www.passportjs.org/docs/configure/